# Can't get init.d or network/if-up.d scripts to start

Tags: init.d

I'm running debian (latest version i believe), and I just can not get my script to run at boot. I've enabled it with update-rc.d, and tried saving it to /etc/network/if-up.d but it just won't start. When I run it manually it works fine. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: what does the script do, does it need to run as a user? post the script.

Comment: It sets up a reverse ssh tunnel to another debian machine.  
  
#!/bin/sh  
### BEGIN INIT INFO  
# Provides:          sshtunnel  
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network  
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs  
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5  
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6  
# Short-Description:  
# Description:       sshtunnel  
### END INIT INFO  
autossh -R 200:localhost:22 [2 more port forwards]  autossh@example.com -p 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working. I had to add the -N argument to the ssh command, and made it run @reboot with crontab like Jacob Evans suggested. Even now that it's working, the login doesn't show in "last" on the receiving end of the ssh tunnel. I had this exact same script without the -N argument working on an older install, and with that setup I could use "last" to see whether it is connected or not. But the important thing is it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Answer, call it in /etc/rc.local before exit 0

or

crontab -e

`@reboot script`

Also try a keepalive script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
nc -z -w5 IP PORT
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
screen -dmS SSHTunnel autosshcommand
else
exit 0;
fi
```

Comment: Already tried rc.local, doesn't work

Comment: ls -lah results?   chmod a+x script and place script in /usr/local/sbin/

Comment: Tried adding it to crontab (with script placed at file system root). When checking the machine the script is supposed to ssh into, "last" outputs this: "autossh  pts/0        [my ip] Sat Nov  7 10:50 - 10:50  (00:00)" So it seems the script is running, but the tunnel is not staying open. This seem to have happend a number of times last night too, when I was trying to run the script from init.d. Which logs should I check to find any errors, except /var/log/daemon.log?

Comment: Launch it into screen or background the process